# Android Studio action bar in dialog appears after expanding dialog size

Tags: android

I have a `tabbed activity` with my `custom theme` that looks like this

[image]

This is the `styles.xml` for that theme

```
<style name="myCustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MyTransparent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name ="android:textColor">@color/PaleBlack</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/PaleBlack</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myCustomButon</item>
</style>
```

I used this line of code to expand the size of the `dialog`

```
getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

But when I do, I get a black bar at the top, which I think is the `action bar`, because when I set the `colorPrimaryDark` to `transparent`, it turned grey. It looks like this

[image]

How can I get rid of the bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Window window = getWindow();
// clear all flags but dim behind
window.setFlags(FLAG_DIM_BEHIND, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```